# Access property name (e.g. self.theProperty) in ObjC

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to read property name but I'm not shore how.
Is it possible in ObjC to get string "theProperty" from self.theProperty?

I know how to read all properties (with "`class_copyPropertyList`") and their names (with "`property_getName`") but couldn't find a way to do something like:

```
NSString *text = [self.theProperty somehowReadThePropertyName]; 
// expected result is: text == @"theProperty"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would get a string representation of the getter for your property:

```
NSString *selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(theProperty));
```

And since you've already used `property_getName` to return a C string, you can get an `NSString` like this:

```
NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property)
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But, what are you trying to accomplish? There may be a far better way to do what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks. 
Code NSString *selectorName = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(theProperty)); is working. 
BUT other version doesn't return NSString and XCode complains with "passing argument 1 of 'property_getName' from incompatible pointer type".

Comment: Whatever you're passing into the `property_getName` function is the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

A problem you have is that when you call `self.theProperty`, you are getting an object of whatever type that property is. That object isn't generally going to know that it is part of another object with a particular property name.

You'll need to get the property name from a higher level than just calling it.