# Pulling out UI Slider Name

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have a `UISlider` interface element that I connected to a property in my view controller called `alphaSlider`. Is it possible to pull out the name of that view controller property at runtime?

The approach I tried was this:

```
NSString *objectName = [slider description];
```

Here is my approach in more detail

```
for (UISlider *slider in sliders)
{
    NSString *objectName = [slider description];
   // Do some stuff with the NSString
}
```

But I discovered that the description is not what I thought it was (it's just a listing of the slider properties).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506195/access-property-name-e-g-self-theproperty-in-objc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you are asking, but it might be `slider.tag`

Comment: I thought about using tags, but then I have to map the tags to property names in a hash, and I was wondering if cocoa has a built in method that helps me avoid that.

Comment: Not sure, I think this might be it.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you have a bunch of UISlider interface elements that are wired to a bunch of UISlider IBOutlets in your code, and you want to figure out which one is the one you have at the moment (in your loop).

Have you tried testing for equality with each of your IBOutlets to find the one that matches? You can do this using == because the pointers will be the same.

Otherwise, I don't believe it is possible since the mapping really only exists in the xib file and is accessed at runtime when the view is being built and the IBOutlets are being populated.

Comment: When I test for equality, what values am I comparing?

Comment: You can compare alphaSlider (or any of your IBOutlet UISlider* pointers) to the sender parameter and whichever matches will identify which slider you have.